# Open PDF file in Mendeley Desktop without making it the default application

Tags: ps2pdf

I am trying to put links into my PDF files that once I click on them, they will directly open the specific file in `Mendeley Desktop`.

This can be easily be done if `Mendeley Desktop` is the default PDF application, but I want to keep `evince` as the default app for PDFs.

The command that I am trying to use is:

```
 \href{run:/home/username/.local/share/mendeleydesktop link/to/pdf/file.pdf}{Title}
```

This command still opens the PDF with `evince`.
When I use the command straight in terminal, it opens in `Mendeley`.
If default pdf application is `Mendeley` then it will open it.